# Not able to open vs2008 project in vs2010

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to open a project developed in vs2008 but i am getting the following error.

"cannot be opened because its project type .csproj is not supported by this version of the application".

And I tried by selecting open with-> visual studio version selector but it opens as a vs2010 project and gives the same error.

Comment: What version of VS 2010 have you installed? If you have an Express version, make sure it is "Visual C# 2010 Express" and not "Visual Basic 2010 Express" or "Visual C++ Express"

Comment: @Anders I'm guessing C# by the file extension `csproj`. OP, do you actually have C# installed?

Comment: If worse comes to worse you can probably create a new project and `add existing` source files from the 2008 directory into the new one and build it again. Surely not the technically correct answer, but one good in a bind, for it's the project file that isn't supported. Odd because I have some toy progs that are forward compatible from VS11 beta to VS2008. Might be for the fact it was beta?

Comment: @Duane sounds like he's trying to open a special project like MVC without having MVC installed. Or a silverlight project without silverlight etc. If its just a C# class library I have a hard time believing it would not work (He could off course have unchecked C# when he installed 2010)

Comment: Are your version of 2008 pro and the 2010 not? Things likes MS Tests etc are not supported in express

Answer (score 2):

When I got this msg, it was because I was opening a "non native" project format. Like e. g. MVC. You would have to install that project-type-extension (if that is the correct name? the one that gives you the project template) for VS2010 as well. I think it even needs to be same version.. like MVC2 again instead of MVC3.

Similar with XNA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you for your kind help.

I was working on a project and it was in vs 2010, same time i tried to open another project for reference which was in vs 2008, even i opened in new instance it was unable to open that.

At end I closed all the VS instances and opened vs 2008 project first, then it asked for version specification.

Did'nt able to rectify the error but got the solution.

"First close all the opened instances and then open the older one".

Answer (score -3):

Just try to open the solution file in an text editor and change the

```
# Visual Studio 2008
```

to

```
# Visual Studio 2010
```

Does it help?

PS: Here are the differences between VS 2008 and VS 2010 sln and csproj files listed:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rextang/archive/2009/07/06/9819189.aspx

You can try to port manually. Just make a backup before you do.

Comment: Visual Studio will automatically upgrade a solution file.  Manually editing them can cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: I did that for downgrading and it was never a problem. I know that it does automatically upgrade, but in the case asked it does not. So why not try it?

Comment: Because it's clearly not the issue.  The solution *does* upgrade, but a specific *project* does not open.  Randomly trying possible solutions to the wrong problem is a good way to make things worse!

Comment: Where is written, that the solution does upgrade? Please point me to that I can't find it in this question. And what is getting worse if you edit a plain text file? Really, try it. If it does not work go back. It costs just a minute. And that it is possible upgrading by just changing some lines in the sln is often stated in the web.

Comment: @Waxolunist: The problem is not with upgrading but with opening. The project is not supported by his version of VS 2010. Not because it is a VS 2008 project, but because the project **type** is not supported by his version.